# Custom Button to Freeze User

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm trying to create a visualforce page that has a lookup field for users, and then one you find a user, I want there to be a custom button. If the user is frozen, I want the user to be unfrozen, and if the user is not frozen, I want the button to freeze the user. I know there is a isFrozen field on the UserLogin object, but from what I can tell that is just able to show whether or not users are frozen, it doesn't deal at all with the freezing/unfreezing of users. Any ideas on how this could be done? Thanks!

## ******Update******

When I try to set the value of the freeze and unfreeze, it says that the field 'uLogin.isFrozen' is not writeable. I've added the code I have so far below:

**Controller**

```
    public with sharing class FreezeUser {

    User_Freeze__c uf;
    User usr;
    UserLogin uLogin;

    public FreezeUser(){
        uf = new User_Freeze__c();
        usr = new User();
        uLogin = new UserLogin();
    }

    public User getUsr(){
        return usr;
    }

    public User_Freeze__c getUf(){
        return uf;
    }

    public UserLogin getULogin(){
        return uLogin;
    }

    public PageReference save(){
        try{
            System.debug('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ userFreeze on BEFORE SAVE: ' + uf);
            upsert uf;
            System.debug('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ userFreeze on AFTER SAVE: ' + uf);
            System.debug('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ userLogin isFrozen AFTER Save ' + uLogin.IsFrozen);
            System.debug('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ userLogin UserId: ' + uLogin);
            //System.debug('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ userLogin UserId: ' + uLogin.id);
        } catch(System.DmlException e){
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            return null;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public PageReference freeze(){
        try{
            System.debug('+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ User isFrozen BEFORE Update ' + uLogin.isFrozen);
            if(uLogin.isFrozen == false){
                uLogin.IsFrozen = true;
                update uLogin;
            }
            System.debug('+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ User isFrozen AFTER Update' + uLogin.isFrozen);

            return null;

        } catch(System.DMLException e){
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            return null;
        }
   }

    public PageReference Unfreeze(){
        try{
            if(uLogin.isFrozen == true){
                uLogin.IsFrozen = false;
                update uLogin;
            }
        } catch(System.DMLException e){
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            return null;
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

**Visualforce**

```
<apex:page controller="FreezeUser">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:messages />

        <!-- Input Section-->
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Select User">
                <apex:inputField label="User" value="{!uf.Usr__c}"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

        </apex:pageBlock>

        <!-- Save Button -->
        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" rendered="{!IF(uf.Usr__c == null, true, false)}"/>

        <!-- Output Section -->
        <apex:pageBlock id="output" rendered="{!If(uf.Usr__c != null, true, false)}">
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Output">
                <apex:outputPanel >
                    <apex:outputLabel value="User: "/>
                    <apex:outputField label="User" value="{!uf.Usr__c}"/>
                    <br/>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="is Frozen: "/>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!uLogin.isFrozen}"/>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <!-- Freeze Button -->
            <apex:commandButton action="{!Freeze}" value="Freeze" rendered="{!If(uLogin.isFrozen == False, true, false)}"/>

            <!-- Unfreeze Button -->
            <apex:commandButton action="{!Unfreeze}" value="Unfreeze" rendered="{!If(uLogin.isFrozen == true, true, false)}"/> 
        </apex:pageBlock>


    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Hey Stephen, by updating the IsFrozen field to true or false, you are essentially freezing or unfreezing the user, just as much as you can deactivate a user based on the value you set the isActive field.

Comment: It's really that easy? Wow. Ok, thanks.

Comment: @sw6-KTBFFHChelseafc, so I tried to update the field, and it said it's not writeable. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like Bob Buzzard has blogged about a way to workaround not being able to set the field via apex, take a look at the full blog post [here](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/freezing-users-from-visualforce.html):

> After digging through the Apex Developer’s Guide and experimenting
>   with the execute anonymous element of the developer console it quickly
>   became clear that I couldn’t freeze a user in Apex.  Searching the
>   SOAP API Developer’s Guide proved more productive when I came across
>   the UserLogin object and its associated IsFrozen field.  While this
>   still mean that I couldn’t use Apex, the SOAP API is accessible via
>   the Ajax Toolkit which I can use from a Visualforce page.
>
> It was then short work to create The Freezer - a Visualforce page to
>   output all usernames present in the system and allow them to be
>   frozen/defrosted at the click of a button.  The page is shown below:

Comment: Thanks. I saw this before, and was hoping there was another way, but it looks like from the support this post got, that this is the way to go.

Comment: I have the button and everything seems to work as an administrator, but when I try to use it as another user it doesn't work, and pops up the "Insufficient Privileges" Error. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Stephen Do they have the "Manage Users" privilege?

Comment: We have them as a Delegated Administrator right now.

Comment: @Stephen it doesn't look like Delegated Administrators can do that at this point, but there is an idea here https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kuEZAAY

Comment: I thought the whole point of Bob Buzzard's article was to create a way to add this capability for non-system administrators? Ugh, classic salesforce.

Comment: @Stephen I think the point is more toward not having to click into each individual user record.

Answer (score 0):

No trickery involving API callouts is necessary - UserLogin.IsFrozen is absolutely "updateable" from Apex, however, check these things:

- Your API version supports it. I used Apex API v33.0. Winter 14, when this feature was released may not have
- You have access edit to the object, record and field in question (I did this as SysAd)
- If you're building a Visualforce controller, you may need to make the controller "without sharing" or have it call a method in a class "without   sharing" should the intended users not have the permission to freeze/thaw users directly
- The relationship from UserLogin to User doesn't seem to be traversable with SOQL
- You're not freezing your own (current) user as the test

Here is quick code demo to run via anonymous apex (yes, I ran this, then copy/pasted it, only anonymizing the username):

```
String uname = 'testuser@sfdcorg.com';
User u = [Select Id, Name FROM User WHERE Username = :uname LIMIT 1];
UserLogin ul = [SELECT Id, UserId, IsFrozen from UserLogin WHERE UserId = :u.Id LIMIT 1];
System.debug(ul);

ul.IsFrozen = true;
update ul;

// Just to be sure I'm reading the stored value
ul = [SELECT Id, UserId, IsFrozen from UserLogin WHERE UserId = :u.Id LIMIT 1];
System.debug(ul);

ul.IsFrozen = false;
update ul;

ul = [SELECT Id, UserId, IsFrozen from UserLogin WHERE UserId = :u.Id LIMIT 1];
System.debug(ul);
```

results in the following log output:

```
17:34:46.252 (252891589)|EXECUTION_STARTED
17:34:46.252 (252913297)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|execute_anonymous_apex
17:34:46.257 (257380661)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[2]|Aggregations:0|SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE Username = :tmpVar1 LIMIT 1
17:34:46.277 (277875089)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[2]|Rows:1
17:34:46.278 (278713872)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[3]|Aggregations:0|SELECT Id, UserId, IsFrozen FROM UserLogin WHERE UserId = :tmpVar1 LIMIT 1
17:34:46.296 (296880812)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[3]|Rows:1
17:34:46.297 (297326250)|USER_DEBUG|[4]|DEBUG|UserLogin:{IsFrozen=false, Id=0Yw80000000eNvbCAE, UserId=00580000003MNpuAAG}
17:34:46.297 (297642255)|DML_BEGIN|[7]|Op:Update|Type:UserLogin|Rows:1
17:34:46.408 (408553415)|DML_END|[7]
17:34:46.408 (408871836)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[10]|Aggregations:0|SELECT Id, UserId, IsFrozen FROM UserLogin WHERE UserId = :tmpVar1 LIMIT 1
17:34:46.440 (440290289)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[10]|Rows:1
17:34:46.440 (440577419)|USER_DEBUG|[11]|DEBUG|UserLogin:{IsFrozen=true, Id=0Yw80000000eNvbCAE, UserId=00580000003MNpuAAG}
17:34:46.440 (440838182)|DML_BEGIN|[14]|Op:Update|Type:UserLogin|Rows:1
17:34:46.480 (480095990)|DML_END|[14]
17:34:46.480 (480462945)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[16]|Aggregations:0|SELECT Id, UserId, IsFrozen FROM UserLogin WHERE UserId = :tmpVar1 LIMIT 1
17:34:46.493 (493842120)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[16]|Rows:1
17:34:46.494 (494130212)|USER_DEBUG|[17]|DEBUG|UserLogin:{IsFrozen=false, Id=0Yw80000000eNvbCAE, UserId=00580000003MNpuAAG}
17:34:46.495 (495471034)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|execute_anonymous_apex
17:34:46.497 (497230588)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

Answer (score -1):

the isFrozen field can be updated. I hope the code below could be of help to you:

```
public with sharing class FreezeUser {
    user u {get;set;}
    public userlogin ul;
    ul = [SELECT Id, UserId,IsFrozen FROM UserLogin WHERE userId =:u.Id][0]; //assuming the user id has been set from the visualforce as you described
    system.debug('ul is: '+ul);
    public PageReference freeze(){      
        if(ul.isFrozen == false){
            ul.isFrozen = true;
            update ul;
        }
        system.debug('ul is: '+ul);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work. Any other ideas?

Comment: What part of the code didn't work? What errors did you get? What was the result of the "system.debug('ul is: '+ul);" statement?

Comment: @sw6-KTBFFHChelseafc there's a bug in your code. `if(ul.isFrozen = false){` should use a double equals for comparison, this is an assignment statement. The code within the scope brackets never gets executed as written.

Comment: @MarkPond - thanks for catching that - missed that one when typing my answer in. Will make the edit to my answer.

Comment: @sw6-KTBFFHChelseafc when I use your code I get "unexpected token: '='" on line 4 where you set the value of userLogin ul. Not sure why I'm getting that.